# 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem with my Database (using MariaDB) to insert a new row

I Having the following errors

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`DbName_boutique`.`Commande`, CONSTRAINT `bdc_managed_by___fk` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`bdc_managed_by_user_id`) REFERENCES `utilisateur`
>   (`utilisateur_id`))INSERT INTO Commande (lien_devis, lien_bdc,
>   end_devis, bdc_status, devis_created_by_user_id,
>   bdc_managed_by_user_id, entreprise_id)

I have this code on my controller :

```
$unknow = NULL;
$end_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 month"));
$user = checkConnected($bdd);
Commande::create($bdd, $new_full_modele_devis_path, $new_full_modele_devis_path, $end_date, 0, $user->getId(), $user->getId(), $entreprise->getId());
```

The $unknow are values I used later in an another Controller.

My Table "Commande" is built like following :

```
create table dBName.Commande
(
  commande_id              int                  not null
    primary key,
  lien_devis               varchar(255)         null,
  lien_bdc                 varchar(255)         null,
  end_devis                datetime             null,
  bdc_status               int                  null,
  devis_created_by_user_id mediumint unsigned   null,
  bdc_managed_by_user_id   mediumint unsigned   null,
  entreprise_id            smallint(5) unsigned null,
  constraint bdc_managed_by___fk
    foreign key (bdc_managed_by_user_id) references dBName.utilisateur (utilisateur_id),
  constraint devis_created_by___fk
    foreign key (devis_created_by_user_id) references dBName.utilisateur (utilisateur_id),
  constraint entreprise___fk
    foreign key (entreprise_id) references dBName.entreprise (entreprise_id)
);
```

And I have later the user table :

```
create table dBName.utilisateur
(
  utilisateur_id        mediumint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
  utilisateur_password  varchar(255) null,
  utilisateur_nom       varchar(50)  null,
  utilisateur_prenom    varchar(50)  null,
  utilisateur_email     varchar(255) null,
  utilisateur_telephone varchar(10)  null,
  utilisateur_fax       varchar(25)  null,
  is_active             tinyint(1)   null
)
  charset = utf8mb4;
```

And entreprise :

```
create table dBName.entreprise
(
  entreprise_id                smallint(5) unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
  entreprise_nom               varchar(100)       null,
  entreprise_siret             char(14)           null,
  entreprise_telephone         char(10)           null,
  entreprise_salesforce_number varchar(100)       null,
  entreprise_compte_client     varchar(100)       null,
  entreprise_raison_sociale    varchar(100)       null,
  entreprise_APE               varchar(25)        null,
  entreprise_image_link        varchar(255)       null,
  adresse_id                   mediumint unsigned null,
  constraint FK_entreprise_adresse_id
    foreign key (adresse_id) references dBName.adresse (adresse_id)
)
  charset = utf8mb4;
```

I don't understand Why i'm Habing the error... And bit of help could help me a lot.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Commande` table, the column `bdc_managed_by_user_id` is mapped to `utilisateur_id` column of `utilisateur` table via foreign key reference.

This means, whenever you insert a row in `Commande` table, corresponding `bdc_managed_by_user_id` has to be one of the `utilisateur_id` present in `utilisateur` table. If not, you will get the above error.

This is called Foreign Key Constraint and you can have a look at [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) example describing how it works.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for your help; I realize that when I say $user-getid(), the return is from my "Client" table and my "utilisateur" table, i need to check why.